How do I ensure unique non-overlapping values in each column?
I have the following input:
    data = {
        'Group_A': ['0&1', '1&5', '0&5', '1&7', '3&8', '4&8', '3&5', '4&4'],
        'Group_B': ['1&0', '5&7', '0&5', '7&7', '4&8', '5&5', '3&2', '4&4']
    }

This is my expected output:



Group_A
Group_B
Group_A_Unique1
Group_A_Unique2
Group_A_Unique3
Group_B_Unique1
Group_B_Unique2
Group_B_Unique3
Match_Count




0&1
1&0
0
1
NaN
0
1
NaN
2


1&5
5&7
NaN
1
5
7
NaN
5
1


0&5
0&5
0
NaN
5
0
NaN
5
2


1&7
7&7
7
1
NaN
7
NaN
NaN
1


3&8
4&8
3
8
NaN
4
8
NaN
1


4&8
5&5
4
8
NaN
NaN
NaN
5
0


3&5
3&2
3
NaN
5
3
2
NaN
1


4&4
4&4
4
NaN
NaN
4
NaN
NaN
2



I will try my best to explain the general rules. The rules are:

The values in Group_X need to be separated by "&", putting each unique value in a separate column.
The unique values in each Group_X_Unique1, Group_X_Unique2, Group_X_Unique3 should not overlap with each other.
It is possible to have more Group_X_Unique columns, but the less the better.
The unique values in each Group_X_UniqueR should match the unique values in each Group_Y_UniqueR.
The Match_Count counts the number of overlaps between Group_A and Group_B.

I’ll illustrate the thought process through a smaller example with 3 datapoints: let's say I want to separate 0&1, 0&5, and 1&5 into individual Group_X_Unique columns. I start with 0&1 -> (0, 1) and 0&5 -> (0, 5). This is fine so far. Now, I want to add 1&5. I cannot simply do 1&5 -> (1, 5) because based on previous entries, 1 exists in the second column. However, 5 is also in the second column. To solve this, I add a third column to get 0&1 -> (0, 1, NaN), 0&5 -> (0, NaN, 5), and 1&5 -> (NaN, 1, 5). Now my requirement is satisfied because 0, 1, and 5 are in their own columns without overlaps. NaN is used as a filler to fill in the 'gaps'.
Note that the output is not unique. From the same 3 datapoints, it is also possible to have (0, NaN, 1), (0, 5, NaN), and  (NaN, 5, 1). Alternatively, (NaN, 0, 1), (5, 0, NaN), and (5, NaN, 1) would also satisfy the rules. All outputs ensure that the unique values are non-overlapping in each column.
I've tried many things but could not arrive to the intended solution. Here is one of my attempts.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'Group_A': ['0&1', '1&5', '0&5', '1&7', '3&8', '4&8', '3&5', '4&4'],
    'Group_B': ['1&0', '5&7', '0&5', '7&7', '4&8', '5&5', '3&2', '4&4']
}

# Load data into DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Extract unique elements from 'Group_A' and 'Group_B'
df[['Group_A_Unique1', 'Group_A_Unique2']] = df['Group_A'].str.split('&', expand=True)
df[['Group_B_Unique1', 'Group_B_Unique2']] = df['Group_B'].str.split('&', expand=True)

# Convert to integers
df[['Group_A_Unique1', 'Group_A_Unique2', 'Group_B_Unique1', 'Group_B_Unique2']] = df[
    ['Group_A_Unique1', 'Group_A_Unique2', 'Group_B_Unique1', 'Group_B_Unique2']].astype(int)

# Identify unique elements for 'Group_A' and 'Group_B'
df['Group_A_Unique3'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Group_A_Unique1'] if row['Group_A_Unique1'] not in [row['Group_B_Unique1'], row['Group_B_Unique2']] else (
    row['Group_A_Unique2'] if row['Group_A_Unique2'] not in [row['Group_B_Unique1'], row['Group_B_Unique2']] else np.nan), axis=1)

df['Group_B_Unique3'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Group_B_Unique1'] if row['Group_B_Unique1'] not in [row['Group_A_Unique1'], row['Group_A_Unique2']] else (
    row['Group_B_Unique2'] if row['Group_B_Unique2'] not in [row['Group_A_Unique1'], row['Group_A_Unique2']] else np.nan), axis=1)

# Count of matching elements
df['Match_Count'] = df.apply(lambda row: sum([row['Group_A_Unique1'] in [row['Group_B_Unique1'], row['Group_B_Unique2']],
                                              row['Group_A_Unique2'] in [row['Group_B_Unique1'], row['Group_B_Unique2']]]), axis=1)

# Rearrange columns to match the desired output
df_output = df[['Group_A', 'Group_B', 'Group_A_Unique1', 'Group_A_Unique2', 'Group_A_Unique3', 'Group_B_Unique1', 'Group_B_Unique2', 'Group_B_Unique3', 'Match_Count']]

# Convert NaN values to 'NaN' string for consistent output format
df_output = df_output.fillna('NaN')

# Reset index
df_output.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

The (incorrect) output is:



Group_A
Group_B
Group_A_Unique1
Group_A_Unique2
Group_A_Unique3
Group_B_Unique1
Group_B_Unique2
Group_B_Unique3
Match_Count




0&1
1&0
0
1
NaN
1
0
NaN
2


1&5
5&7
1
5
1
5
7
7
1


0&5
0&5
0
5
NaN
0
5
NaN
2


1&7
7&7
1
7
1
7
7
NaN
1


3&8
4&8
3
8
3
4
8
4
1


4&8
5&5
4
8
4
5
5
5
0


3&5
3&2
3
5
5
3
2
2
1


4&4
4&4
4
4
NaN
4
4
NaN
2




Could you be more clear about where to put the NaNs? I'm not sure if I get the logic.

it looks like each row is dependent on the previous ones: if there's already a 1 in one column, all 1s should belong to that column?

Could you indeed elaborate a bit. E.g., for Group A: you have 1&5 -> (NaN, 1, 5), and then next row 0&5 -> (0, NaN, 5). Why? What would be wrong with (1, 5) and (0, 5)?

@diggusbickus Yes, that's exactly right. The main idea is to have non-overlapping unique values in each Group_X column, so if there's a 1 in Group_A_Unique1, all 1s should only go to that column and not in Group_A_Unique2 or Group_A_Unique3

@U13-Forward @ouroboros1 I'll try to illustrate with an example. Let's say I want to separate 0&1, 0&5, and 1&5 into individual columns. I start with 0&1 -> (0, 1) and 0&5 -> (0, 5). This is fine. Now, I want to add 1&5. I cannot simply do 1&5 -> (1, 5) because based on previous entries, 1 exists in the second column. However, 5 is also in the second column. To solve this, I add a third column to get 0&1 -> (0, 1, NaN), 0&5 -> (0, NaN, 5), and 1&5 -> (NaN, 1, 5). Now my requirement is satisfied because 0, 1, and 5 are in their own columns without overlaps.

I hope my example was clear. NaN is basically used as a filler to fill in the 'gaps'. Please let me know if I can provide further clarification.

don't add important information in the comments: edit your question instead

the rules are still unclear to me: is the output unique? with the rules you have given the answer is no, but your comments seem to contradict that

The output is not unique. I've edited the question with further examples for clarification.
